# Turning on a rgb headlamp with red first

Tags: gear, headlamps

I currently own a PETZL TACTIKKA + RGB 2019 which offers the possibility of making red, green and blue (and of course white) light.

It's a good lamp but the white light is the first light to turn on when the lamp is turned on and I don't find it very practical when I want to turn it on in an environment where I have to be discreet.

I would like to know if there is the same type of lamp but which offers, when switching on, the colors and lastly the color white.

Comment: I don't know if this is your exact model, but the Petzl website for [TACTIKKA® +RGB](https://www.petzl.com/US/en/Sport/SPECIALIZED-headlamps/TACTIKKA-PLUSRGB) has a [Technical notice](https://www.petzl.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0681r00000DT50kAAD) download which in turn says: "If the lamp is turned off in color mode, it re-lights in the selected color."

Comment: ...if so you can prepare the lamp before entering the sensitive area.

Comment: I have a Coleman headlamp, only red or several brightness levels of white - that turns on red first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I own a [Black Diamond Spot 325](https://www.blackdiamondequipment.com/en/headlamps-and-lanterns/spot-325-headlamp-BD620641_cfg.html) - it doesn't have RGB capacity, but it does have red/white and the switch between them is a simple button push that cycles between 2 white modes (spot and spread) and 1 red. The headlamp "remembers" which of the settings you last used and re-starts in that setting. I don't know if it will remember this setting after taking out the batteries, but I suspect not.